# Verify tar backup on an lto5

Tags: backup

Is there a terminal command to verify a tar backup on an LTO5 tape. Once I back up all my files I want to be able to view file size and or number of items to verify backup was complete. I do not know if it can be done.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`tar -tvf /path/to/tape` should do the trick. If its a big archive, then pipe through more
e.g. `tar -tvf /path/to/tape | more`